# Is Addition of Char and Boolean Expression results in Boolean result?

Tags: c, boolean

In the following function

The statement  `s[i] + s[i] == c;` results in either zero or one (Boolean result).

My question: will the above expression be converted to boolean expression? It is considering the value of `s[i]`

```
void func(char s[], int c)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i] + s[i] == c;
    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is incorrect.  The expression `s[i] + s[i]==c` is equivalent to `(s[i] + s[i]) == c`.  Therefore, it is not "addition of char and boolean expression".

The result is a boolean expression, but note that there is no primitive `bool` type in C.  So this expression will be of type `int`, with a value of either `1` or `0`.  So therefore, the value of `s[j]` will be either `1` or `0`.

Comment: C has a `bool` type(def), defined as `_Bool` in `stdbool.h`. However the result of the `==` operator is an `int` not a `bool`.

Comment: @R.. have to note that `_Bool` is available in C99 and might not be available when other dialects of C are used. In Objective-C (strict superset of C) there is `BOOL`.

Comment: @R., @Oli, `_Bool` is always available with a conforming compiler. "stdbool.h" additionally provides `bool`, `false` and `true`. Still Oli you are correct, the results of such expressions are `(int)0` and `(int)1`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no boolean type in C, at least not unless you dive into the mostly unused parts of the standard.

Expressions that, semantically speaking, have boolean values, are managed by the compiler as `int`s with value 1 (for true) and 0 (for false). You can then assign that value to a `char`, and it will be appropiately down-casted/demoted.

This:

```
char a, b, c;
a = (b == c);
```

Works like this:

```
char a, b, c;
a = (b == c) ? 1 : 0;
```

Both 1 and 0 are of integer type, demoted to char on assignment.

Comment: -1+1=0 because there is a boolean type, called `_Bool`, but your are right for the return type of the expressions

Comment: @Jens as a I said above, IMO, mostly unused parts of the standard. I, for one, have never run into code that uses _Bool.

Comment: If seen many that use its more user-friendly derivative `bool` that is provided by "stdbool.h". And I have seen many ad hoc definitions of `TRUE` `FALSE` and whatever, although there are `true` and `false` available.